# Unable to see spring starter project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I have eclipse IDE luna 4.4.0 installed on my sytsem. I also installed Spring Tool Suite 3(3.9.8.Release) and Spring Tools 4- for spring boot(4.1.0.Release). I am unable to see Springstarter project in eclipse under new project option.

Comment: You are unable to see option for creating spring boot project in Eclipse Luna or STS?

Comment: Did you install anything in Eclipse or did you just install the separate stand-alone STS which doesn't add anything to Eclipse? Eclipse Luna is quite old and the current Spring Tools code probably won't run on it.

Comment: Neither STS 3.9.8 nor Spring Tools 4 are compatible with Eclipse Luna (4.4).

Comment: @XeshanJ There are two ways to create spring boot application one by installing STS from eclipse market place. I installed STS as mentioned above but I am unable to create spring boot project(because I am unable to see spring starter project under new option in eclipse ). Meanwhile I am using second option, creat spring boot project from https://start.spring.io and import in eclipse as existing maven project.

Comment: @MartinLippert I installed new version of eclipse than install STS from eclipse market place. Now I can see Springstarter project in eclipse under new project --> SpringBoot .

Answer (score 4):

Restart the eclipse IDE after the spring installation. If it is still not showing then go to file => new => other => expand spring boot in the wizard screen => able to see "spring starter project"

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem while installing **Spring Tools
3 (Standalone Edition) 3.9.13.RELEASE)**.

How I solved? By reinstalling it:

1. Uninstall STS: **Help> Eclipse Marketplace > Installed** then on **Spring Tools 3 (Standalone Edition) 3.9.13.RELEASE)** click **change** then uninstall
2. Then install again and don't forget to restart Eclipse once finished

I hope I have helped.

Answer (score 0):

install spring tool4 Help> Eclipse Marketplace > Installed then on Spring Tools 4